# Modify elements of a layout from another class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I am a student and a beginner in java and android.

I am modifying an android application which allows to configure bluetooth beacons. With the original application we can only configure the beacons one by one, therefore I want to modify the application to be able to configure a good number automatically.

**I have a problem when I want to modify an element in the layout of a class from another class.**

**From the Main class I can interact well with the elements of the Main layout. But since the Main class, I can't interact with other layouts (PasswordDialog in my case).** I've been struggling for several days, I tried responses to similar posts but without success because the configuration of my classes is quite special and I don't want to modify them too much so as not to alter the functioning of the application. If anyone has any leads, I would be very grateful;)

The main class:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener, MokoScanDeviceCallback, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// ...

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        // ...
        final PasswordDialog dialog = new PasswordDialog(this); // Another function which already calls the PasswordDialog class which interests me
        dialog.setSavedPassword(mSavedPassword);
        dialog.setOnPasswordClicked(new PasswordDialog.PasswordClickListener() {
        // ...
        }

}   

@OnClick({R.id.iv_about, R.id.iv_refresh, R.id.bt_auto})
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        // ...
        case R.id.bt_auto: // When I click on the bt_auto button, the code below is executed
            final PasswordDialog dialog = new PasswordDialog(this); 
            dialog.AutoSetPassword("Moko4321"); // the method I'm trying to launch
        // ...
    }
}
// ...
```

}

Now here is the PasswordDialog class which is in another package. I want to modify an element of the passworddialog layout from my Main class :

```
public class PasswordDialog extends BaseDialog  {
@Bind(R.id.et_password) 
EditText etPassword; // The element that I want to modify

public PasswordDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

// ...

public void AutoSetPassword(String pass) { // My method to modify the EditText
    etPassword.setText(pass); // This does not work
    // and
    ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password)).setText(pass); // If I try this instead, it's the same
}
```

}

Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: Don't really understand what you want to modify but does it have any reason to instantiate two Password Dialogs in onItemClick and onClick. May be the instance you see on UI is not the one you apply etPassword.setText("Moko4321");  ?

Comment: @BorislavKamenov First of all thank you for helping me, I will try to be clearer.

Basically, you have to press different buttons and fill in certain fields to configure the beacons. Each button executes code.

I would like to simulate clicks with performClick() and automatically fill in the fields that interest me to create a kind of maccro.

This is why there is the original onItemClick function which will execute code and then my onClick function which will launch the different stages of my macro by simulating clicks and filling in fields.